# Difference of using implib versus coff2omf when creating an importlib for DLL

Tags: dll, c++builder

C++ Builder comes with two tools that helps consuming DLL's compiled with other compilers.

In short, to use exported functions in a DLL, the DLL is often accompanied with an import library and a header file. These files are used during compiling and linking for convenience, as one can also load functions in a DLL dynamically.

When a DLL is created with another compiler, e.g. Visual Studio, the import library is not recognized by C++ Builder (wrong format).

The utility program **coff2omf.exe** can convert an import library generated by Visual Studio to be suitable for the Codegear linker.

However, there is another utility, **implib.exe**, that can generate an import library as well. implib.exe operates directly on the DLL, and creates an import library from what it finds out by looking at the DLL internals (I assume).

Question is, what's the difference in the resulting import library, if any?

Is there a preference using one over the other?

C++ Builder is a compiler sold by Embarcadero, formerly owned by Borland.

Comment: That is an opinion question. It might be closed. But why don't you simply test this? Use implib on a DLL for which you have a coff .lib file already. Convert that using coff2omf and then compare the results, e.g. with TDump.

Comment: FWIW: "CodeGear"? Which version are you using? It has been Embarcadero for quite some time now.

Comment: Codegear is a division, or at lest it was, of Embarcadero afaik.
implib seems to do the job perfectly. I'll get back with a coff2omf vs implib test.

Comment: CodeGear was a subsidiary of Borland **before it was sold to Embarcadero in 2008, i.e. 10 years ago.** Then the name became Embarcadero. CodeGear was never a division of Embarcadero, AFAIK. Anyway, "Codegear have" is wrong.

Comment: From wikipedia: CodeGear is a wholly owned division of Embarcadero Technologies. Are you saying that Wikipedia is wrong(!!) :)
I'm happy to change it to C++ builder..

Comment: it **was** a wholly owned division of Borland. It may have kept that name for a short while after the sale (IIRC, the former DB division of Embarcadero were even renamed DataGear), but those names soon disappeared.

Comment: You use coff2omf.exe on a .lib file to *convert* an import library to OMF format.  You use implib.exe on a .dll file to *generate* an import library.

Comment: Hans, I understand that. Question is: Is there a difference and/or preference using one over the other?